# How can I use arrays to save at most 20 records?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

In this program, I can only use arrays to save at most 20 animal name but there is a error on line 6. The error is

> The method createAnimalName(String) is undefined for the type of animalDirectory.

How can I correct this error?

```
public static void storeAnimal() {
             for(int j=0; j<=19; j++) {   ///at most 20 records
                System.out.println("Add animal name:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
                String animalName = input.nextLine();
                createAnimalName(animalName); 
                break;
              }
        }

         public static void createAnimalName () {
             if (createAnimalName <=19) {                               
                    System.out.println("Saved: "+ animalName);          
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Full");
                }

         }
```

Comment: post complete code

Comment: Is `createAnimalName()` a `static` method of the **same** class?

Comment: Yes, please post complete code.  The fact that you haven't shown us where `createAnimalName` is defined or the class it's defined it completely removes our ability to help you.

Comment: Please post all relevant code. it looks method createAnimalName is not defined in class `AnimalDirectory`. again I am assuming Since I can't have a full picture of your code.

Comment: this is pretty evident from the code posted. You do not have a method named as createAnimalName with a String argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in that you are attempting to pass a variable to a method which does not accept any values!

```
         public static void createAnimalName (String createAnimalName) {                              
                System.out.println("Saved: "+ createanimalName);
         }
```

This should work for you! You don't need to check anything because the loop doesn't run more than 20 times, so just printing that the animal name is saved will work.